# Ionic App not reflecting changes to the screens

Tags: ionic2

Here is my System info
Your system information:

```
Your system information:
Cordova CLI: 7.1.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v9.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

My ionic app was working fine few months back. Now I am trying to make changes but they are not being reflected on the screens. I have changed my node version to 6 but still not working.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you an `ionic serve`, did you directly deploy on your device...?

Comment: I have tried all
ionic serve
phonegap serve
deployed on device
But the changes not appearing 
Now I have created a New Ionic app and transferring all of my files. Once completed then I will see if it is working or not. 
I have tried by downgrading the appscript version but still it is getting the 3.0.0 version some how while I am trying to downgrade with 2. some thing which I saw in my other ionic app working good,

Comment: @FarrukhQamar have you registered a service worker? Check your index.html to see if the service worker part is commented out. If not, the service worker will cache all resources and use the cached version instead of the newest version being hosted with ionic serve. If it has already registered open chrome inspector, go to Application tab, under Service Worker, unregister it. To fix on devices uninstall them, and after commenting the service worker part in the index.html, redeploy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution.I have checked and the service worker part is already in comments.

Comment: I have just checked the problem seems to be in the Phonegap serve. When I access my app via ionic serve then the changes are reflected but if I access via Phonegap serve then changes are not being reflected.